# Azure Cloud Shell Unknown Error

Tags: azure-cloud-shell

Since yesterday I am trying to start the Azure Cloud shell but every time I am getting the following error:

Sorry, something went wrong: Unknown Error

See attached image.
[image]

To troubleshoot I  tried to delete the Cloud Shell Resource Group (cloud-shell-storage-westeurope) and its storage account.
After restarting the Cloud Shell I was asked to create the RG and storage account for the Cloud Shell again. But the problem was still there.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for that experience - we've recently been resolving this issue as it is a bug on our end. We've released a few hotfixes that will hopefully fix this issue, if you still hit it please try simply exiting the shell and launching it again. If at this point you still repeatedly receive this error, please open a support ticket with us [here](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/newsupportrequest).

Thanks for your patience and for being a Cloud Shell user!

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I am using the Azure Cloud Shell a lot and last couple of days is working well again!

Comment: Good to hear - please send us feedback at aka.ms/cloudshell/feedback ! We're always looking to make your experience better!